# Add table row dynamically in Android?

Tags: android

I need to add table row by using Java code only (not XML design).

In that table row I have to add two textview fields. I use the code below.

```
 TableRow tblrow=new TableRow(this);
 tblrow.addView(Textview1);
 tblrow.addView(Textview2);
```

But it only displays Textview1. How to view both?

I am new to Android.

Answer (score 2):

```
TableRow  tr1;  
//TableRow  tr2;    
TextView txt9;

TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length-1; i++)
{
    string_arr = fun1.split(str_arr[i].trim(),"^");
    tr1 = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
    txt9=new TextView(this);
    txt9.setText(strinarr[0]);
    txt9.setBackgroundColor(intblue);
    txt9.setTextColor(intwhite);
    tr1.addView(txt9);
    tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams));
}
```